# Unable to create PDF in Android 11(R)

Tags: android, pdf, itext

Greetings to community

I am generating PDF reports using ITEXT library.

> 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.6'

I am doing this like that

> ```
>  Document document = new Document();
> ```

```
   fileName = FileName + Common.getCurrentDateTime() + ".pdf";
   
    fileName1 = FileName + Common.getCurrentDateTime() + ".pdf";
    String dest = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/RTS";

    File dir = new File(dest);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();


    try {
        File file = new File(dest, fileName);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        //FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        //PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
        //  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("PdfError", e.toString());
        //   dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("PdfError", e.toString());
        //  dialog.dismiss();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please note that this solution is working fine till Android (10)Q.
I have gone through many solution and spend almost a week with this problem.
I am testing Android (11)R scenario on Emulator.

**Now PDF has created thanks to people who comment on this question**

> ```
>  document.close();
> ```

```
    //   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");
    File file = new File(dest+"/"+fileName1);
    // File file = new File("/" +"Internal storage"+ "/" +"RTS" +"/" + fileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    ((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);
    listsOfListReportModelList.clear();
```

Now unable to open file like this.
Saying to make name shorter.

Comment: Access to external storage has been changed in Android 11. Please check out this [guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: Stop writing to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. You do not have write access to that location anymore. Use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`. Or, use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to let the user choose where on the user's device (or the user's cloud storage) you should be putting the user's PDF.

Comment: Thank you for guiding, I am apply these suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderHoffmann  now file is generating but unable to open it through this.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare now file is generating but unable to open it through this

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` has been effectively banned for about five years. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution to create and display PDF in Android 11

Create @xml/provide_paths.xml in resource directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

Add this is Manifest.xml application tag

```
     <application
<--other properties-->
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

     <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Now create and display PDF

```
    String fileName1 = "";
Document document = new Document();
    // Location to save
    fileName1 = "TEST" + ".pdf";
    String dest = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/";

    File dir = new File(dest);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();


    try {
        File file = new File(dest, fileName);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("PdfError", e.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("PdfError", e.toString());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Open to write
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph(""));
        document.add(new Chunk(""));
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


      document.close();

    File pdfFile = new File(dest+"/"+fileName1);
    if (!pdfFile.exists()) {
        pdfFile.mkdir();
    }



    if (pdfFile != null && pdfFile.exists() ) //Checking for the file is exist or not
    {
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);


        Uri mURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context,
                context.getApplicationContext()
                        .getPackageName() + ".provider", pdfFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(mURI, "application/pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(context, "The file not exists! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

This is  how you can make PDF through iText library and can display it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your well working solution!

Comment: Any other solution without using android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: I have not found any solution with out using android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in Android 11.

Comment: @Rakesh Polo, Requesting legacy external storage has no effect for an Android 11 device. It is only needed for an Android 10 device. But never for getExternalFilesDir().