# Android 11 - File.listFiles() is not return some extension files

Tags: android

I'm developing app on Android 11.
Permissions added:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But when use File.listFiles() on my Dowload folder, it only return .jpg, .png, .mp4, some media extension files.

When .txt, .pdf, .doc...etc extensions files is not return.

When i change targetAPI to 28. This issues is gone.
What happen then?
Did anybody have solutions or cause of it?

Demo code:

```
 private void DebugListingFile()
{
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for(File file : files)
    {
        Util.LogError(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have access to arbitrary files in arbitrary directories on Android 11+. If you need to support all MIME types, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` from the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare: With 2 types of action you suggest and only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, can i list all mime types?

Comment: Because all i need is read and list file, not modify it.

Comment: My strong recommendation would be to eliminate "list file" from your app. Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and allow the user to pick a piece of content. The OS will provide the "list file" UI for you, in a standard form that the user is likely to have seen before. If you insist that your app needs to list content, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, `DocumentFile`, and the `listFiles()` on `DocumentFile`. See the blog post series beginning with [this post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) for more.

Comment: Your problem is not about mime tyes but of owners of files. An app on an Android 11 device  will only see its own files and media files like from Camera app. If your app created those .txt and .doc files you could list them.

Comment: @blackapps: With your knowledge, for now, have anyway to list all files without use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Comment: No, sorry, that will not go. But SAF will be your friend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260807/unable-to-create-pdf-in-android-11r/66277111#66277111 
This might help you, It is little bit related to your concern.