# Create folder and store file in android 11

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-backups, android-10.0, android-11

I'm working on an Android app that uses a SQLite database for storing survey data.

> Problem: For Android version 10 and above devices,I can't store a backup copy of an SQLite database in some folder that won't be deleted even if app is uninstalled

For devices before Android version 10 it works fine with code below:

```
 folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Db_Backup");// Folder Name

 if (!folder.exists())
    folder.mkdirs(); //Db_Backup folder gets created
```

For devices with Android version 11,it is not working

**For android 10 and 11 devices, I have tried using code as below:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
   Files[] files=getExternalFilesDirs(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
   folder=files[0]; 
   // OR
   folder = getFilesDir();

   if (!folder.exists())
      folder.mkdirs(); // Db_Backup folder is created in app directory 
   ......
}
```

Above code creates a backup copy to **android/data/com.example.packagename/files/backup/{filename.db}**  this location only

> Issue: when app is uninstalled or app data gets cleared the .db backup file also gets removed or cleared

exportDatabaseNew() function that I am using is as below:

```
    private void exportDatabaseNew(LinearLayout linearLayout) {

    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        File dbFile = getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
        File[] files;
        File folder = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            files=getExternalFilesDirs("Db_Backup");
            folder=files[0];
            Log.i("export", "exportDatabaseNew: " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Db_Backup");//Folder Name
            Log.i("export", "exportDatabaseNew: " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        String currentDate = df.format(new Date());
     
        String backupName = "Survey_" + currentDate + ".db";

        File myFile = new File(folder, backupName);// Filename

        output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
      
        Snackbar.make(linearLayout, R.string.backup_complete, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Db_Backup");` 'Db_Backup' is no public external folder hence not usable as parameter there. Use Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS for instance.

Comment: Please look into the following link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260807/unable-to-create-pdf-in-android-11r/66277111#66277111

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I find it amazing how difficult it is to backup/export/import a simple .db file in Android 11 and have it accessible to the user upon uninstall/re-install of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own folder in public Documents directory and write your file to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

For Android 11, you have to either:

1. Save files in your application directory
2. Save files into public directories
3. If you really must, any other location that is NOT a different app directory, it requires the following permission:

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>

This permission only applies for android 11 and above. Do note that if you want your app to be published on Google Play Store you'll need to provide a good reason why you want this permission and you are not willing to simply store it as part of your app's files.

Comment: re: 2. I found that if you save files in public folders (e.g. Documents), you no longer can access them if you uninstall and reinstall your app when targeting API 30. I tried following the dev guide in using intents to get permissions, but I haven't managed to get it working yet.